# FileOutputStream write binary file to a specified folder

Tags: java, serialization, fileoutputstream

I'm trying to write a binary file to a specified folder, however it keeps giving me an exception.
For example, if I write the file without specifying any folder the program writes it with no problem:

```
public void saveFile(String name) throws IOException {
    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(name + ".bin"));
    out.writeObject(this);
    out.close();
}
```

However, when I try to specify the folder the program just doesn't write the file:

```
public void saveFile(String name) throws IOException {
    File location = new File("/path/" + name + ".bin");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(location);

    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    out.writeObject(this);
    out.close();
    fos.close();
}
```

I tryed several different ways but still no solution.
Does anybody know what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Write the stack trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the class which you want to write is `Serializable` or not.

```
public class Foo implements java.io.Serializable{   

    //...

    public void write() throws IOException{
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("Test.bin"));
        os.writeObject(this);
        os.close();
    }   

}
```

**Another problem:**
If there is no folder named `path` it cannot write the object

Check your code again.

Comment: Yes, it is serializable.
The way you are using is the way I can do, without specifying any path. That way I can do it with no problem.

Comment: Check if there is a folder named the name you want.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you very much, dude :)
I thought that the program would create the path automaticaly, but it seems that I was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The Only reason seems for non Serialization is that u might not have implemented Serializable interface
and give your path name correctly for eg:-"C:\Users\.."
Hope it works

Comment: The problem was that I was typing a non existing path. I thought that the program would create that path but it doesn't...